# Casting an mpz_class temporary to int

Tags: c++, gmp

As part of my code's logic, I'm assigning the result of an expression involving mpz_class to an int. The problem is, mpz_class overloaded operators don't seem to produce mpz_class objects, but rather, some kind of temporaty object that then gets converted to mpz_class (if I understood [this](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Internals.html) correctly). Because of this Is there any way that I can convert the result of bignum % 10 to an int inline?

```
int digit_sum = 0;
while(bignum > 0) {
    digit_sum += bignum % 10;
    bignum /= 10;
}
```

Comment: `mpz_class(bignum%10).get_si()`, but you would probably be better off using the lower-level `mpz_fdiv_ui`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GMP library uses expression templates to avoid unnecessary temporary variables.  As such, `bignum % 10` returns a proxy that represents the expression and only evaluates when converted to `mpz_class`.  Also, `mpz_class` does not implicitly convert to `int`.  Therefore, as mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57192415/casting-an-mpz-class-temporary-to-int/57193208#comment100895225_57192415), you need to first convert to `mpz_class` and then use the [`get_si`](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers) method to convert the `mpz_class` to `long`.

```
digit_sum += mpz_class{bignum % 10}.get_si();
```

Note that in general, you need to make sure that the number actually fits into `long` before calling `get_si`.  In this case, the (absolute) number is always less than 10, so it is safe to call `get_si`.